# Is "model selection" the same as traning?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, terminology, train

A terminology problem. In machine learning we have the following problem:

Choosing the optimal model (or training): 
$$
f^* = \arg\min_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sum_i l(x_i,y_i)
$$

Is the term "model selection" always "exactly" referring to this? Or something else?

Comment: No, because model selection can have additional cost constraints (such as reducing complexity of $f$).

Comment: Could you elaborate? Or could you give me some pointers?

Comment: No. In many approaches, for example SVM, training means solving a given optimization problem which itself is parametrized. Model selection means finding the right parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best model is not necessarily the model which minimizes error, but typically attempts to reduce overfitting bias by [adding penalties for cost complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29) and  by cross-validating between training and validation samples.

[web.engr.oregonstate.edu/cs534 slides](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~xfern/classes/cs534/notes/model-selection-11.pdf&ei=AJ9uUoCzJM_figLYp4CADQ&usg=AFQjCNG37gEoA8QlmK1hPAkKhJrGWKDkeA&bvm=bv.55123115,d.cGE)

Answer (score 1):

Training often involves model selection (choice of model structure, set of input variables, transformations, ...). But, as @MarcClaesen pointed out, training also includes the process of fitting the model, i.e. finding best values for its parameters.